# Stretched button in DiagonalLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, graphics, awt

I have a small problem with the layout diagonalLayout proposed on the site of oracle ...
In fact I would just stretch the last button on the width of my screen while keeping the layout and I can not, but I've tried this code:

```
    public void stretchLastComponent(Container container){
            int nComps = container.getComponentCount();
            Component c = container.getComponent(nComps-1);

            c.setSize(container.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
```

I also use repaint () and revalidate (), but without result.
Here is the class used (it was an imposed job I can not change the layout):

[DiagonalLayout.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CustomLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/DiagonalLayout.java)

And I also supplied in code for simplicity in the forum:

```
    package layout;

/*
 * 1.2+ version.  Used by CustomLayoutDemo.java.
 */

import java.awt.*;

public class DiagonalLayout implements LayoutManager {
    private int vgap;
    private int minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0;
    private int preferredWidth = 0, preferredHeight = 0;
    private boolean sizeUnknown = true;

    public DiagonalLayout() {
        this(5);
    }

    public DiagonalLayout(int v) {
        vgap = v;
    }

    /* Required by LayoutManager. */
    public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
    }

    /* Required by LayoutManager. */
    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
    }


private void setSizes(Container parent) {
    int nComps = parent.getComponentCount();
    Dimension d = null;

    //Reset preferred/minimum width and height.
    preferredWidth = 0;
    preferredHeight = 0;
    minWidth = 0;
    minHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nComps; i++) {
        Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
        if (c.isVisible()) {
            d = c.getPreferredSize();

            if (i > 0) {
                preferredWidth += d.width/2;
                preferredHeight += vgap;
            } else {
                preferredWidth = d.width;
            }
            preferredHeight += d.height;

            minWidth = Math.max(c.getMinimumSize().width,
                                minWidth);
            minHeight = preferredHeight;
        }
    }
}


/* Required by LayoutManager. */
public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
    int nComps = parent.getComponentCount();

    setSizes(parent);

    //Always add the container's insets!
    Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
    dim.width = preferredWidth
                + insets.left + insets.right;
    dim.height = preferredHeight
                 + insets.top + insets.bottom;

    sizeUnknown = false;

    return dim;
}

/* Required by LayoutManager. */
public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
    int nComps = parent.getComponentCount();

    //Always add the container's insets!
    Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
    dim.width = minWidth
                + insets.left + insets.right;
    dim.height = minHeight
                 + insets.top + insets.bottom;

    sizeUnknown = false;

    return dim;
}

/* Required by LayoutManager. */
/*
 * This is called when the panel is first displayed,
 * and every time its size changes.
 * Note: You CAN'T assume preferredLayoutSize or
 * minimumLayoutSize will be called -- in the case
 * of applets, at least, they probably won't be.
 */
public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
    Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
    int maxWidth = parent.getWidth()
                   - (insets.left + insets.right);
    int maxHeight = parent.getHeight()
                    - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
    int nComps = parent.getComponentCount();
    int previousWidth = 0, previousHeight = 0;
    int x = 0, y = insets.top;
    int rowh = 0, start = 0;
    int xFudge = 0, yFudge = 0;
    boolean oneColumn = false;

    // Go through the components' sizes, if neither
    // preferredLayoutSize nor minimumLayoutSize has
    // been called.
    if (sizeUnknown) {
        setSizes(parent);
    }

    if (maxWidth <= minWidth) {
        oneColumn = true;
    }

    if (maxWidth != preferredWidth) {
        xFudge = (maxWidth - preferredWidth)/(nComps - 1);
    }

    if (maxHeight > preferredHeight) {
        yFudge = (maxHeight - preferredHeight)/(nComps - 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nComps ; i++) {
        Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
        if (c.isVisible()) {
            Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();

             // increase x and y, if appropriate
            if (i > 0) {
                if (!oneColumn) {
                    x += previousWidth/2 + xFudge;
                }
                y += previousHeight + vgap + yFudge;
            }

            // If x is too large,
            if ((!oneColumn) &&
                (x + d.width) >
                (parent.getWidth() - insets.right)) {
                // reduce x to a reasonable number.
                x = parent.getWidth()
                    - insets.bottom - d.width;
            }

            // If y is too large,
            if ((y + d.height)
                > (parent.getHeight() - insets.bottom)) {
                // do nothing.
                // Another choice would be to do what we do to x.
            }

            // Set the component's size and position.
            c.setBounds(x, y, d.width, d.height);

            previousWidth = d.width;
            previousHeight = d.height;
        }
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    return getClass().getName() + "[vgap=" + vgap + str + "]";
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where in the code are you calling `stretchLastComponent`?

Comment: What is the problem? What do you want this code to do and what does it actually do?

Comment: I 've created this method in the DiagonalLayout.java

Answer (score 2):

You can't/shouldn't change the size/position of any component which under the control of a layout manager, the next time the container is validated (laid out) those values will be rest by the layout manager...

Now having said that, since you have access to the source code of the layout manager, you have the ability to effect how it makes it's decisions...

By simply adding this into the `layoutContainer` method, right before `c.setBounds(x, y, d.width, d.height);`

```
if (i == nComps - 1) {
    d.width = parent.getWidth();
    x = 0;
}
```

I was able to achieve this...

[image]

**UPDATED after feedback**

I've fudged the layout code a little to allow the layout to perform the way you image suggest...

[image]

```
public class TestLayout14 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout14();
    }

    public TestLayout14() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                LayoutPane layoutPane = new LayoutPane();
                content.add(layoutPane);
                content.add(new ControlPane(layoutPane), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(content);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class LayoutPane extends JPanel {

        public LayoutPane() {
            setLayout(new DiagonalLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Test 01"));
            add(new JLabel("Test 02"));
            add(new JLabel("Test 03"));
            add(new JButton("Test 04"));
        }
    }

    public class ControlPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField fieldGap;
        private JCheckBox majorDiag;
        private JCheckBox streatchLast;
        private LayoutPane layoutPane;

        public ControlPane(LayoutPane pane) {

            layoutPane = pane;

            setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 0, 0, 0), new MatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.GRAY)));

            fieldGap = new JTextField(Integer.toString(((DiagonalLayout)layoutPane.getLayout()).getVgap()), 4);
            majorDiag = new JCheckBox("Major Diagnal");
            streatchLast = new JCheckBox("Last Component Stretched");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(new JLabel("Diagnal Gap: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(fieldGap, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(majorDiag, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(streatchLast, gbc);

            fieldGap.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        ((DiagonalLayout) layoutPane.getLayout()).setVgap(Integer.parseInt(fieldGap.getText()));
                        layoutPane.invalidate();
                        layoutPane.revalidate();
                    } catch (Exception exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            streatchLast.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ((DiagonalLayout) layoutPane.getLayout()).setStreatchLast(streatchLast.isSelected());
                    layoutPane.invalidate();
                    layoutPane.revalidate();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public class DiagonalLayout implements LayoutManager {

        private int vgap;
        private int minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0;
        private int preferredWidth = 0, preferredHeight = 0;
        private boolean sizeUnknown = true;
        private boolean streatchLast = false;

        public DiagonalLayout() {
            this(5);
        }

        public DiagonalLayout(int v) {
            vgap = v;
        }

        public void setVgap(int vgap) {
            this.vgap = vgap;
        }

        public int getVgap() {
            return vgap;
        }

        public void setStreatchLast(boolean streatchLast) {
            this.streatchLast = streatchLast;
        }

        public boolean isStreatchLast() {
            return streatchLast;
        }

        /* Required by LayoutManager. */
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        }

        /* Required by LayoutManager. */
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
        }

        private void setSizes(Container parent) {
            int nComps = parent.getComponentCount();
            Dimension d = null;

            //Reset preferred/minimum width and height.
            preferredWidth = 0;
            preferredHeight = 0;
            minWidth = 0;
            minHeight = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < nComps; i++) {
                Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                if (c.isVisible()) {
                    d = c.getPreferredSize();

                    if (i > 0) {
                        preferredWidth += d.width / 2;
                        preferredHeight += vgap;
                    } else {
                        preferredWidth = d.width;
                    }
                    preferredHeight += d.height;

                    minWidth = Math.max(c.getMinimumSize().width,
                            minWidth);
                    minHeight = preferredHeight;
                }
            }
        }


        /* Required by LayoutManager. */
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
            int nComps = parent.getComponentCount();

            setSizes(parent);

            //Always add the container's insets!
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            dim.width = preferredWidth
                    + insets.left + insets.right;
            dim.height = preferredHeight
                    + insets.top + insets.bottom;

            sizeUnknown = false;

            return dim;
        }

        /* Required by LayoutManager. */
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
            int nComps = parent.getComponentCount();

            //Always add the container's insets!
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            dim.width = minWidth
                    + insets.left + insets.right;
            dim.height = minHeight
                    + insets.top + insets.bottom;

            sizeUnknown = false;

            return dim;
        }

        /* Required by LayoutManager. */
        /*
         * This is called when the panel is first displayed,
         * and every time its size changes.
         * Note: You CAN'T assume preferredLayoutSize or
         * minimumLayoutSize will be called -- in the case
         * of applets, at least, they probably won't be.
         */
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            int maxWidth = parent.getWidth()
                    - (insets.left + insets.right);
            int maxHeight = parent.getHeight()
                    - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
            int nComps = parent.getComponentCount();
            int previousWidth = 0, previousHeight = 0;
            int x = 0, y = insets.top;
            int rowh = 0, start = 0;
            int xFudge = 0, yFudge = 0;
            boolean oneColumn = false;

            // Go through the components' sizes, if neither
            // preferredLayoutSize nor minimumLayoutSize has
            // been called.
            if (sizeUnknown) {
                setSizes(parent);
            }

            if (maxWidth <= minWidth) {
                oneColumn = true;
            }

//            if (maxWidth != preferredWidth) {
//                xFudge = (maxWidth - preferredWidth) / (nComps - 1);
//            }
//
//            if (maxHeight > preferredHeight) {
//                yFudge = (maxHeight - preferredHeight) / (nComps - 1);
//            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nComps; i++) {
                Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                if (c.isVisible()) {
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();

                    // increase x and y, if appropriate
                    if (i > 0) {
                        if (!oneColumn) {
                            x += previousWidth / 2 + xFudge;
                        }
                        y += previousHeight + vgap + yFudge;
                    }

                    // If x is too large,
                    if ((!oneColumn)
                            && (x + d.width)
                            > (parent.getWidth() - insets.right)) {
                        // reduce x to a reasonable number.
                        x = parent.getWidth()
                                - insets.bottom - d.width;
                    }

                    // If y is too large,
                    if ((y + d.height)
                            > (parent.getHeight() - insets.bottom)) {
                        // do nothing.
                        // Another choice would be to do what we do to x.
                    }

                    if (isStreatchLast() && i == nComps - 1) {
                        d.width = parent.getWidth() - x;
                    }

                    // Set the component's size and position.
                    c.setBounds(x, y, d.width, d.height);

                    previousWidth = d.width;
                    previousHeight = d.height;
                }
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            String str = "";
            return getClass().getName() + "[vgap=" + vgap + str + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's supposed to be activated when selecting the checkBox.I've tried to use the setBounds method in a new method but it doesn't works .

Comment: Thank you for help.
It's just like this :
http://i639.photobucket.com/albums/uu116/wadjo/box1.jpg

Comment: There is no solution to that ?

Comment: Thanks.
But i can't integrate that Class, i don't know how ... 
Can you help me with a simple example ?

Comment: That's a full running example, what more do you want?

Comment: Really thank you.
I've tried this line and it was correct as i expect : c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(container.getWidth(), c.getHeight())); Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried this code : c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(container.getWidth(), c.getHeight())); And this is it !
Another time, thank you.